# The scene does not split for logic editing

Tags: data-blocks

I am facing a problem with splitting the screen in half for logic editing.

Whenever I drag the top right triangle, the scene does not split.

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor is in position to split the area, it should change to a cross.

If you have trouble dragging the corner, try <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on the edge of the editor and choosing split area.

[image: split area menu]

To make clicking on the edge easier, you can change the line width to thick in the preferences.

[image: line thickness option]

Also of note is that in 2.80 the ability to split an area from the corners can be turned off.

[image: 2.80 interface options]